# Connection with professor

Tags: graduate-admissions, communication

I have applied for an integrated MS and PhD program. I have sent am email for that purpose. The professor had an interview of me via skype. Then he sent me 6 of his papers and told me read those. At the same time, he told me to apply for scholarship via the general admission process of his university.  I am now reading those papers.

But I am confused that whether he is positive to me or not. What should I do at this stage?

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that he is a bit positive and a bit neutral. I hope he knows a bit about you from your earlier contact. Otherwise he has no reason for anything but neutrality.

Read the papers. Make notes. If you are interested in that subject matter you could then ask one or two questions based on those papers. Even questions about things you don't (yet) understand can be valuable at this stage. But you might just get pointed to more papers. But if you work with this person, there will be papers and papers.

But it is likely a mistake to flood him with questions (or emails). Start the long term relationship gradually. But don't be shy about expressing interest if you really have it.

But, for any future conversation, even by email, make sure you are informed about his interests and research direction.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the professor followed up to your interview in any way is at least a mild positive; if they had no interest in you they likely would not have had any more interaction with you.

However, depending on where you are applying, the professor may have little influence on your application success; in North America at least, graduate admissions is often kept separate from individual professor's preferences. So even if the professor is positive, telling you to apply to the general process may be all they can do at the moment.

Do as the professor suggests, and good luck with your application.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds generally positive to me: after an interview it's hard to know how good a student is, so the professor probably came out of it cautiously optimistic, and waiting for further indications that you're good.

Other relevant points: the question mentions "applying for scholarship", which to me implies admission + funding.
Regarding admission, as iayork's answer says, graduate admissions are usually separate from the professors' preferences, so you have to go through that process. Typically you might identify a prospective supervisor somewhere in the application, and they will be consulted -- it doesn't guarantee anything, but it means that the student will probably have someone to do his/her research with. So here it's good that you talked to this professor ahead of the application process, and I would guess that he'll have a positive recommendation, otherwise he would probably have discouraged you from applying.
Also note that after admission you have a fair bit of coursework and general training ahead of you, so during that time you probably won't be working too closely with the professor. But if he gave you those papers, it's also a way of pointing you in the right direction to get familiar with the research area.

As for funding, if I understand correctly he's asking you to look for funding elsewhere, but this doesn't imply that he doesn't want to hire / pay you. Ideally, you can get other funding, which is a win-win: it's good for your CV, and for him it means he can hire you with less strain on his research grant.